# regular expression exclude minified files with watchr

Tags: ruby, regex, watch

I try to use Ruby watchr to watch all assets but already minified and run minify at change:

```
watch('^(css|js)/.+(?!\.min)\.(css|js)') {
    |md| system('sh #{md[1]}/minify.sh')
}
```

Somehow this does not work because the .+ is to greedy. In PHP you can use .+? to make less greedy, but how to do this for Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/139200), the `.+?` is a valid regular expression in Ruby as well.